# How to add elements to datalines dynamically

Tags: sas

I am trying to create Dataset using the Dataline option based on the data that the user input. Is there a way to add the values in Dataline dynamically in stored process? If not how do I go about doing this?

EDIT: I am getting input from user as an array of numbers. I want to add few more fields to form my dataset. So in short, the dataset i am trying to create is a combination of array elements from the user and some more data based on these input numbers.

User inputs: 1234, 2345, 3456

Dataset:
number   |    text       |    id
1234     | "Something 1" | 1
2345     | "Something 2" | 2
3456     | "Something 3" | 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datalines/cards shouldn't be used in any sort of production system.  Among other things, they're illegal in an %include, which is often used in production systems.

I believe the default in a stored procedure is to return macro variables (based on the `name` given to the field in the input form).  Either directly assign that to a dataset variable, or if it's a lot of text that you want to parse, write the macro variable out to a text file and read it in.  More information for the proper way to handle this for your case might be available with more information in the question.

Given the edits, and assuming you get the value `1234, 2345, 3456` in a macro variable `&number`, you can do something like this:

```
data want;
_numvar = "&number.";
do _t = 1 to countc(_numvar,",")+1;
  number = scan(_numvar,_t,",");
  text = catx(" ","Something",substr(number,1,1);
  id = input(substr(number,1,1));
  output;
  keep number text id;
end;
run;
```

I don't know how you're constructing `text` and `id` so I just made something up there.

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding

Comment: I will try in this direction. Just one small thing, the &number is an array and not string. But I guess I will be able to handle that. Thanks.